# Disadvantages of Ubuntu installed inside the Win vs next to Win

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, windows

Are there any disadvantages of installing Ubuntu inside the Win using installator vs next to Win using bootable device?

For example: My user account (on Win) contains `diacritics` which causes problems when installing Python modules using `pip` or `setup.py`.

Comment: There are pros and cons for both setups.

Answer (score 3):

A WUBI setup is...

- Easier to install (on older systems - UEFI users sometimes have issues)
- Doesn't require a new bootloader (which Windows can munch)
- Doesn't require repartitioning your Windows drives to make room
- Is slower than native because it's one step removed from hardware
- Can still get munched by Windows. Windows will ultimately do whatever Windows wants to do.
- Still requires you to have partitions (albethem virtual) for Ubuntu so you still have to allocate space.
- Other than on disk speed, as fast as a native install
- Needs you to reboot to switch between OSes.

In you case it doesn't sound like you need a full desktop install of Ubuntu. A virtualised (VMWare, VirtualBox, VirtualPC, etc) install of Ubuntu inside Windows would probably be enough and would be a lot more convenient, in that it lets you run both at once.

Of course if you find you need the performance element in Ubuntu, you could flip the tables and install Windows in a virtual machine under Ubuntu.